video display error 224002 recent download 20.04.6
I have Ubunbtu 20.04.6 installed on several machines with varied hardware recently that do not have this problem ... BUT my recent download of 20.04.6 (past 2 months) has resulted in the 224002 error report for two specific sources, Free Speech TV and Democracy Now.
I have confirmed the existence of the video plugin OpenH264 codec and Widevine content decryption.  I have confirmed adequate RAM and adequate startup device space.
So,  what has changed?
